# I am found in maturity, and in senility lost

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

Me again. You know what to do by now

> I am found in maturity, and in senility lost.
>
> I am present in the innovators, who push on, no matter the cost.
>
> If you are a carpenter, then I am a daily action.
>
> If you are a bank, I <s>supervise</s> record every transaction.
>
> To the needy, I attract, and to the rich I often repel.
>
> If you try me for to long, you should probably set a spell.
>
> I won't be easy in the start, but you should really try.
>
> You're likely to need me someday, so tell me.... What am I?

Here's your chance for a comeback, Twinkie. Good luck, and as always, feedback on my riddles is much appreciated. I have written quite a few of them today, so let me know what you think.

Hint:

> I have many meanings, with differences abound.
>  If my meaning seems consistent, then I have not been found.

Hint #2:

> I have many meanings, as you can clearly see.
>  If this seems too easy, then do not be deceived.
>  See, my meaning even differs within a single clue.
>  If you should forget this fact, then no check mark for you!

Also, don't forget about that last line. This time, it has a bit of significance

**EDIT**

A lot of people are having trouble with this one, so I changed one of the words in the riddle to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it

> Drive

I am found in maturity, and in senility lost.

> Driving licences become available when someone becomes an adult (matures) and can be removed in old age

I am present in the innovators, who push on, no matter the cost.

> innovators are driven to do suceed

If you are a carpenter, then I am a daily action.

> a carpenter would drive a screw

If you are a bank, I record every transaction.

> Transactions would be recorded on a disk drive

To the needy, I attract, and to the rich I often repel.

> owning a car to drive is aspirational, the rich often prefer chauffeurs

If you try me for to long, you should probably set a spell.

> after a long drive people generally need to sit for a bit

I won't be easy in the start, but you should really try.

> learning to drive is complicated but rewarding in the long run

You're likely to need me someday, so tell me.... What am I?

> driving is a major method of transportation which most people (in the developed world) are likely to need to do at some point

Comment: Crossposted with Kevorobin

Comment: This is awkward... Which one of you was first?

Comment: Timestamp says not me, they hit post just after I started typing

Comment: Regardless, you had the proper reasoning. 100% correct!

Comment: Well, 95%. See if you can figure out where you went wrong with your reasoning in the fifth clue ("To the needy"). Your interpretation works, but is not the one I was thinking of

Answer (score 4):

Ah man... I'm no good at crafty words...

> for hilarity, wood

I am found in maturity, and in senility lost.

> Multi-meaning words, huh? Need I explain? viagra.

I am present in the innovators, who push on, no matter the cost.

> wood > build > "build upon yourself" and all that jazz... and I guess if your innovator is *male,* then they can certainly *push on*.

If you are a carpenter, then I am a daily action.

> They work with wood. Do they work with their own wood? :)

If you are a bank, I supervise every transaction.

> uh... no puns here, sorry.

To the needy, I attract, and to the rich I often repel.

> Wood to build houses. .... nobody wants some woody. put that away.

If you try me for too long, you should probably set a spell.

> There's a limit to how much wood you can have, or something might burn...

I won't be easy in the start, but you should really try.

> Come on now, don't be shy... give it a try!

You're likely to need me someday, so tell me.... What am I?

> Need those kids, dontcha?

Comment: This is a good answer, fits most of the clues. However, the third clue is specific to Carpenters, not just anyone

Comment: Your new answer is closer, the answer is a word much like the one you have guessed. One word, a pretty abstract concept. See my hint

Comment: Still pretty close, but no cigar. Remember, one meaning of this word is an action that is relatively specific to carpenters

Comment: @Cubemaster I botched it- just finding random words related to wood, now... AND I have to head home. Rats. I'll update with a truly inspiring answer before I leave ;)

Comment: Good to hear. I am writing one more before I head home myself, I am liking how it is coming out

Answer (score 4):

I am going to go with something funky, some of the clues are a stretch so I doubt its the answer but the fun is in guessing. I thought of more general ones that seem to fit everything but they were always too consistent in their meaning, going against what OP hinted at; Anyway, here goes :P

> I am a Mat

I am found in maturity, and in senility lost.

> **mat**urity  and not found in senility, this one is literal.

I am present in the innovators, who push on, no matter the cost.

> Innovators often attempt using new mats (or materials) in new inventions, or endeavors.

If you are a carpenter, then I am a daily action.

> Mat Carpenter is a baseball player for the cardinals. In can also be a large slab usually of reinforced concrete used as the supporting base of a building. But to be honest, a carpenter(trade) wouldn't have too much to do with that.

If you are a bank, I supervise every transaction.

> Minimum alternative tax( MAT)

To the needy, I attract, and to the rich I often repel.

> The needy might want mats to sit down or sleep on while the rich seriously would NEVER use them, unless maybe for yoga

If you try me for too long, you should probably set a spell.

> Perhaps this is a reference to card games that use game mats (like magic?)

I won't be easy in the start, but you should really try.

> MAT exams

Comment: I like. I click.

Answer (score 3):

Are you a

> Draft?

I am found in maturity, and in senility lost.

> People who draft papers and things are more mature. People who are senile just write crazy things.

I am present in the innovators, who push on, no matter the cost.

> Innovators go through many drafts in their inventions, it's part of the engineering process.

If you are a carpenter, then I am a daily action.

> Carpenters work as drafters (people who draw designs for things).

If you are a bank, I supervise every transaction.

> [Bank Draft](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/bank_draft.asp)

To the needy, I attract, and to the rich I often repel.

> I believe this is referring to war drafts. They appeal to the needy, because the army provides food, shelter, and pay. However, rich people will often avoid war drafts at all costs, because they could get killed.

If you try me for too long, you should probably set a spell.

> Not too sure on this one, but maybe it's referring to how writers get attached to bad drafts of their writing? Spell here is a play on that because writers have to spell.

I won't be easy in the start, but you should really try.

> Yes, first drafts are always the hardest to write.

Comment: Definitely on the right track, but do you really think I would have the same solution for [two riddles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/69224/in-the-olden-days-i-was-feared-for-my-name-meant-certain-death)?

Comment: @Cubemaster, to be fair, I didn't know your other one had been solved yet, nor that that was the answer.

Comment: @Cubemaster that would be really sneaky though, it's a pretty good fit here too.

Comment: That's true, it is a pretty good fit

Answer (score 3):

I had a guess but never posted it because it doesn't quite fit all the clues but since nobody has gotten it yet, I'll share.

> A drive?

I am found in maturity, and in senility lost.

> Sex drive

I am present in the innovators, who push on, no matter the cost.

> A drive that push forth to accomplish something

If you are a carpenter, then I am a daily action.

> Driving a screw

If you are a bank, I supervise every transaction.

> A hard disk drive that records every transaction

To the needy, I attract, and to the rich I often repel.

> This is where I'm stumped.

If you try me for to long, you should probably set a spell.

> You sit all the time when driving a vehicle and sometime it can be quite exhausting. Not sure at all about this one.

I won't be easy in the start, but you should really try

> Stumped again but a stretch would be learning how to drive?

Comment: Technically right, but I am giving it to Finoc for the better explanation. Still, mighty fine job!

Answer (score 2):

A dodgy response, but is it

> Tacks / Tax

I am found in maturity and senility lost

> Well oddly, when an investment matures and you earn income, you then have to pay tax.  And when you are senile, you are no longer sharp as a tack.

I am present in the innovators who push on no matter the cost

> Innovation is all about finding a new tack (direction) to solve a problem.

If you are a carpenter, I am a daily action

> Possibly the most obvious part, tacks are nails.

If you are a bank, I supervise every transaction

> Not only is tax involved, but also TACs which are Transaction Authority Codes.

To the needy I attract, and to the rich I often repel

> An oft-cited problem of tax is that the needy tend to pay more, at least proportionally.  Rich people can pay someone to help them avoid it. Also, putting something back together that has broken could be "tacking something together", which is unlikely to be done by the rich who would simply buy another one (eg clothing).  Also also "tack" is the derogatory term for cheap items rather than good quality items that are more expensive.

If you try me for too long, you should probably set a spell

> I guess doing anything for too long is quite taxing on the body

I won't be easy in the start, but you should really try

> Tacking into the wind (in a boat) requires effort, but it lets you move against opposition, and without requiring an engine.

You're likely to need me someday, so what am I?

> The best I have here is that thumbtacks (pushpins) are are common enough item and almost everyone has used them at some point.

Answer (score 2):

I'll opt for:

> Check

I am found in maturity, and in senility lost.

> Maturity check.

I am present in the innovators, who push on, no matter the cost.

> They check into things, investigating them

If you are a carpenter, then I am a daily action.

> Checking measures.

If you are a bank, I supervise every transaction.

> A check.

To the needy, I attract, and to the rich I often repel.

> A rubber check? Checks are more likely to bounce for poor people than for rich ones.

If you try me for to long, you should probably set a spell.

> Don't check your spelling yourself, use a spell checker.

I won't be easy in the start, but you should really try.

> Playing chess, you should attempt to place your opponent in check, which isn't easy during the first moves.

You're likely to need me someday, so tell me.... What am I?

> A medical check up, especially when you get older.

Comment: I like the wordplay here. You are certainly on the right track, the word I am thinking of has similarly different meanings. Not the right answer, but pretty good!

Answer (score 1):

Is it...

> Integrity?

I am found in maturity, and in senility lost.

> As people become senile, the usually lose track of their previous morals

I am present in the innovators, who push on, no matter the cost.

> Perseverance could be seen as an aspect of integrity

If you are a carpenter, then I am a daily action.

> Integrity of a structure is important to keep it from collapsing

If you are a bank, I supervise every transaction.

> Banking systems need to ensure the integrity of their data and avoid corruption

To the needy, I attract, and to the rich I often repel.

> Sometimes being poor/rich can cause people to behave morally/immorally

If you try me for to long, you should probably set a spell.

> No idea about this one

I won't be easy in the start, but you should really try.

> It takes dedication to build your integrity

You're likely to need me someday, so tell me.... What am I?

> I'm not too sure about this one. "Character" was another that came to mind but didn't seem to fit.

Comment: I like this interpretation, but if you see my hint this is ruled out. Integrity has only one meaning, or very few at a stretch.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is

> RULE

I am found in maturity, and in senility lost.

> self-rule

I am present in the innovators, who push on, no matter the cost.

> They rule!

If you are a carpenter, then I am a daily action.

> They measure things with a ruler

If you are a bank, I supervise every transaction.

> Rules

To the needy, I attract, and to the rich I often repel.

> The rich don't want to be bound to rules

If you try me for to long, you should probably set a spell.

> People who try to rule for too long turn into dictators, better limit the time

I won't be easy in the start, but you should really try.

> Learning a new habit, getting used to a new rule, is hard at first

Answer (score 1):

My guess is ...

> Track

I am found in maturity, and in senility lost.

> You keep track of everything until you're senile

I am present in the innovators, who push on, no matter the cost.

> When you're innovating, you're following all the tracks possible.

If you are a carpenter, then I am a daily action.

> Refering to the group of music ? ^^'

If you are a bank, I supervise every transaction.

> As a bank, you track every transaction.

To the needy, I attract, and to the rich I often repel.

> Rich don't like to track everything ?

If you try me for too long, you should probably set a spell.

> If you run on a track for too long, you need to rest

I won't be easy in the start, but you should really try.

> Write/Play music is not easy in the start

Comment: Not a bad guess, you have the right sort of word, just not the right one

Answer (score 0):

> Change:

Maturity is

> knowing how, and when to

Innovators

> are all about it

Carpenters

> change the world, and their building plans

Financial transactions

> require correct change

Poor people

> look for change, rich people can say 'keep the change'

Too much

> change in your life, yeah, you'll need a break

It's hard to

> start a change

And yes,

> we'll all need to change something...

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE. Please help others enjoy the puzzle by using the >! markup to hide the spoiler-y parts of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am most likely wrong, but could the answer be

> Intelligence/Being Smart

I am found in maturity and senility lost

> When we mature and learn new things, we gain knowledge, but as we grow senile, we tend to forget things

I am present in the innovators who push on no matter the cost

> Many smart people are known to make changes to our technological lives. Also, historically, the scientists who lived in the late Medieval-early Renaissance had a large cost to pay for innovating science in ways against the Church

If you are a carpenter, I am a daily action

> Requires a lot of precision and math, two things that are basically synonymous with intelligence

If you are a bank, I supervise every transaction

> Be smart with your money

To the needy I attract and to the rich I often repel

> A lot of the millionaires we pine over aren't too smart sadly, and if you are curious about learning all sorts of things, you are needy for knowledge

If you try me for too long, you should probably set a spell

> Many spellbooks such as the Grand Grimoire tell us how to cast spells, but they are known for being cryptically worded.

I won't be easy in the start, but you should really try

> Many hate school when they start the real focus on learning, but students are motivated to try their best

You're likely to need me someday, so what am I?

> To learn about what you're going into as a career, especially if a lot of mathematics and science are involved

Answer (score 0):

'To the needy, I attract, and to the rich I often repel.'

> Uber. Everyone drives for Uber, but CEOs keep quitting.

Comment: I can't comment on the answer because I don't have any rep.